# Google Maps Marker Incorrect position in IE, working fine on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have plotted a route map on my page using google API. Now let say I have printed a route map from point A to Point B which goes from point C. Now I am Showing some marker with point C in the map. It works fine with Chrome but Don't work with Internet Explorer.

Here is my code. To run it select a address from list and click on submit

```
<html>
<head>
    key=25888957881@project.googleusercontent.com
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Waypoints in directions</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .labels 
        {
            color: red;
            background-color: white;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            width: 40px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  language=javascript>

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
        var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;


        function SetfC(src) {
            document.getElementById('id1').focus();
            src.blur();
        }

        function ShowPhoneNumber(address, Number, Text) {

            codeAddress(address, Number, Text);
        }


        function codeAddress(address, Number, Text) {

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    draggable: true,
                    raiseOnDrag: true,
                    map: map,
                    labelContent: Number,
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(results[0].geometry.location),
                    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                    labelStyle: { opacity: 0.75 },
                    icon: {}
                    });
                    var iw1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: Text
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function (e) { iw1.open(map, this); });
                }
                else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });

        }

        function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: chicago

            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));


            calcRoute();
        }

        function calcRoute() {

            var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
            var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
            var waypts = [];
            var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected == true) {
                    ShowPhoneNumber(checkboxArray[i].value, 'NUM', 'Rohit  ');

                    waypts.push({
                        location: checkboxArray[i].value,
                        stopover: true
                    });
                }
            }

            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                waypoints: waypts,
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    var route = response.routes[0];
                    var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
                    // For each route, display summary information.
                    for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                        var routeSegment = i + 1;
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <input onclick="alert(2+2)" type="button" id="id1" value="click"/>

    <select id="opt" onfocus="SetfC(this);" onmouseup="SetfC(this);">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>



    <div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:60%;height:85%;"></div>
    <div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
    <div style="margin:20px;border-width:2px;">
    <b>Start:</b>
    <select id="start">
        <option value="Halifax, NS">Halifax, NS</option>
        <option value="Boston, MA">Boston, MA</option>
        <option value="New York, NY">New York, NY</option>
        <option value="Miami, FL">Miami, FL</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <b>Waypoints:</b> <br>
    <i>(Ctrl-Click for multiple selection)</i> <br>
    <select multiple id="waypoints">
        <option value="VILLA RICA, 65 E INDUSTRIAL CT, GA, 30180-1037 Time: 12:00PM to 1:00 PM">Montreal, QBC</input>
        <option value="4025 PLEASANTDALE RD, DORAVILLE, GA, 30340-4262 Time: 00:00AM to 1:00 AM">Toronto, ONT</input>
        <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</input>
        <option value="winnipeg, mb">Winnipeg</input>
        <option value="fargo, nd">Fargo</input>
        <option value="calgary, ab">Calgary</input>
        <option value="spokane, wa">Spokane</input>
    </select>
    <br>
    <b>End:</b>
    <select id="end">
        <option value="Vancouver, BC">Vancouver, BC</option>
        <option value="Seattle, WA">Seattle, WA</option>
        <option value="San Francisco, CA">San Francisco, CA</option>
        <option value="Los Angeles, CA">Los Angeles, CA</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();">
    </div>
        <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="directionsPanel" style="float:right;width:30%;height 100%"></div>
    <p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span></p>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: in The IE browser we can get ,but when ever you open it show's on the top of the browser, below to the menu you will get 'to help protect you security....' on that line right click then on 'Allow blocked content' and press on alert box 'yes' then you can see...

Comment: I am already doing so but still the marker label come at extreme top left.

Comment: I get javascript errors in IE: `Object doesn't support property or method 'setOnLoadCallback' 
v3_SO_markerErrorIE.html, line 163 character 9` and `'marker1' is undefined 
v3_SO_markerErrorIE.html, line 108 character 13`; when I fix those `'computeTotalDistance' is undefined 
main.js, line 28 character 1252`

Comment: I have removed the function but still errors are coming in IE that I am unable to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Marker was not accepting the Anchor point. So I changed the code form

```
labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(results[0].geometry.location)
```

to

```
labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22,0)
```

And now it is coming at correct position

Comment: `results[0].geometry.location` will be a `latLng` object. It's hard to see why the original statement would have worked in Chrome.

Comment: Yes you are right. I also thought the same after searching for the reason.

Comment: Rohit, I guess the Chrome thing will remain a mystery. It's best if you accept your own answer now. That's totally acceptable on StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lays here:
[Google Maps JavaScript API Error In Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857081/google-maps-javascript-api-error-in-internet-explorer)

Basically, your need to declare map as a Global variable.
Like so:

```
var map;
```

In a global context.